# Angular formArray reset with value

Tags: angular

Why is this so hard to reset a form with formArray to it's default value ?

I found lot of issue about "clearing" formArray, but not much about reset to initial value (including delete/add formControl from FormArray to match initial model).

The most functional workaround I found is this awful piece of code :

```js
this.formGroup = undefined;
setTimeout(() => this.setForm(data), 100); // setForm populate this.formGroup, timeout mandatory...
```

For the love of javascript, why form.reset(value) can't do the job ?
Is there any cleaner workaround ?

- formArray.reset(value) won't do as it only reset each formControl to it's default value, but won't add/delete them to match initial formArray.
- formArray.clear() won't do ever as it's will not re-create deleted entry from initial values. (+ null value without new NonNullable form type)
- NonNullable control won't do the trick for new/deleted formArray entry, it simply reset it but don't delete/add formControl to formArray.
- FormBuilder won't help as it's just a different api to create FormGroup.

~setForm code:

```js
this.data = {x: [{ mail: "abc@test.com", reveive: true }] };
this.validators =  [Validators.required, Validators.email];

setForm(data) {
  this.formGroup = new FormGroup({
    x: new FormArray(data.x.map((v) => new FormGroup({ 
        mail: new FormControl(v.mail, { validators }),
        receive: new FormControl(v.receive)
       })
    ))
  })
}
```

```js
// Try to reset newly added entry
this.formGroup.get('x').push(new FormGroup({
  mail: new FormControl('xyz@test.com', { validators }),
  receive: new FormControl(true)
}));

this.formGroup.reset(this.data);
this.formGroup.get('x').length === 2 // true :(

...
// Try to recreate deleted entry
this.formGroup.get('x').removeAt(0);

this.formGroup.reset(this.data);
this.formGroup.get('x').length === 0 // true :(

...
// hardcore reset
this.formGroup = undefined;
setTimeout(() => this.setForm(data), 100);
this.formGroup.get('x').length === 1 // true :/
```

Entry deleted in FormArray then formGroup.reset(value) ? => FormArray would still be empty.
Entry added in FormArray then formGroup.reset(value) ? => FormArray would still have 2 entries instead of one (with the newly entry set to null if it wasn't NonNullable type).

Comment: What about simply setting the form array to an empty array?

Comment: @derstauner formArray.clear() will fit for this usecase.
But I don't want to clear it, I want to reset it to initial value.
Clearing the FormArray won't do as I will have to re-populate it with proper data and validators.